# Parse Chat error

Tags: ios, chat, parse-platform

I am trying to make a chat based on Parse I followed this tutorial http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com but when I try to send a message the app crashes and this exception appears:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'
```

I have been trying to fix it but I can't find the reason for this error so now I am trying to find help. This is my code:

```
#import "DMChatRoomViewController.h"
#import "chatCell.h"
@interface DMChatRoomViewController ()

@end

@implementation DMChatRoomViewController
@synthesize tfEntry;
@synthesize chatTable;
@synthesize chatData;
#define MAX_ENTRIES_LOADED 25


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
tfEntry.delegate = self;
tfEntry.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
[self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
if (_refreshHeaderView == nil) {

    PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - chatTable.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, chatTable.bounds.size.height)];
    view.delegate = self;
    [chatTable addSubview:view];
    _refreshHeaderView = view;
}
//  update the last update date
[_refreshHeaderView refreshLastUpdatedDate];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear{
className = @"chatroom";
userName = @"John Appleseed";
chatData  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self loadLocalChat];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Chat Room

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
[self freeKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Chat textfield

-(IBAction) textFieldDoneEditing : (id) sender
{ 
NSLog(@"the text content%@",tfEntry.text);
[sender resignFirstResponder];
[tfEntry resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction) backgroundTap:(id) sender
{
[self.tfEntry resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
NSLog(@"the text content%@",tfEntry.text);
[textField resignFirstResponder];

if (tfEntry.text.length>0) {
    // updating the table immediately
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"text", @"userName", @"date", nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tfEntry.text, userName, [NSDate date], nil];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
    [chatData addObject:dictionary];

    NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [insertIndexPaths addObject:newPath];
    [chatTable beginUpdates];
    [chatTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [chatTable endUpdates];
    [chatTable reloadData];

    // going for the parsing
    PFObject *newMessage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"chatroom"];
    [newMessage setObject:tfEntry.text forKey:@"text"];
    [newMessage setObject:userName forKey:@"userName"];
    [newMessage setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];
    [newMessage saveInBackground];
    tfEntry.text = @"";
}

// reload the data
[self loadLocalChat];
return NO;
}


-(void) registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}


-(void) freeKeyboardNotifications
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
-(void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSLog(@"Keyboard was shown");
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
CGRect keyboardFrame;
[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y- keyboardFrame.size.height+49, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSLog(@"Keyboard will hide");
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
CGRect keyboardFrame;
[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + keyboardFrame.size.height-49, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Data Source Loading / Reloading Methods

- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource{

//  should be calling your tableviews data source model to reload
//  put here just for demo
_reloading = YES;
[self loadLocalChat];
[chatTable reloadData];
}

- (void)doneLoadingTableViewData{

//  model should call this when its done loading
_reloading = NO;
[_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:chatTable];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

[_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

[_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView];

}
#pragma mark - Parse

- (void)loadLocalChat
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:className];


// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
if ([chatData count] == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    NSLog(@"Trying to retrieve from cache");
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu chats from cache.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
            [chatData removeAllObjects];
            [chatData addObjectsFromArray:objects];
            [chatTable reloadData];
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
__block int totalNumberOfEntries = 0;
[query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The count request succeeded. Log the count
        NSLog(@"There are currently %d entries", number);
        totalNumberOfEntries = number;
        if (totalNumberOfEntries > [chatData count]) {
            NSLog(@"Retrieving data");
            int theLimit;
            if (totalNumberOfEntries-[chatData count]>MAX_ENTRIES_LOADED) {
                theLimit = MAX_ENTRIES_LOADED;
            }
            else {
                theLimit = totalNumberOfEntries-[chatData count];
            }
            query.limit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:theLimit];
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    // The find succeeded.
                    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu chats.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
                    [chatData addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                    NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    for (int ind = 0; ind < objects.count; ind++) {
                        NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ind inSection:0];
                        [insertIndexPaths addObject:newPath];
                    }
                    [chatTable beginUpdates];
                    [chatTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                    [chatTable endUpdates];
                    [chatTable reloadData];
                    [chatTable scrollsToTop];
                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }

    } else {
        // The request failed, we'll keep the chatData count?
        number = [chatData count];
    }
}];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate Methods

- (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

[self reloadTableViewDataSource];
[self performSelector:@selector(doneLoadingTableViewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

}

- (BOOL)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceIsLoading:(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

return _reloading; // should return if data source model is reloading

}

- (NSDate*)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceLastUpdated:(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

return [NSDate date]; // should return date data source was last changed

 }
#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [chatData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
chatCell *cell = (chatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"chatCellIdentifier"];
NSUInteger row = [chatData count]-[indexPath row]-1;


if (row < chatData.count){
    NSString *chatText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize size = [chatText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(225.0f, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
    cell.textString.frame = CGRectMake(75, 14, size.width +20, size.height + 20);
    cell.textString.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    cell.textString.text = chatText;
    [cell.textString sizeToFit];

    NSDate *theDate = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
    cell.timeLabel.text = timeString;

    cell.userLabel.text = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"userName"];
}
return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:chatData.count-indexPath.row-1] objectForKey:@"text"];
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(225.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

return labelSize.height + 40;
}

-(void)presentChatNameDialog
{
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Chat Name"
                                                  message:@"Choose a chat name, it can be changed later in the Options panel"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];

[message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
//    [message setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.7765f green:0.1725f blue:0.1451f  alpha:1.0f]];
//    [message setAlpha:0.8f];
[message show];
}

@end
```

Comment: This is caused by `userName` being `nil`.

Comment: Please narrow down your code to just the relevant parts of the issue.

Comment: You've added more keys to your dictionary than objects. I would assume that either tfEntry.text or userName are nil. Therefore those items can't be added to the dictionary. Trying using NSLog to log those items before trying to create your dictionary to confirm they actually exist.

Comment: Thank you! I already fix it but know I have a different error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'